# DIV Refresh on a Object File

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a DIV that loads a text file. The goal is to update the text file and have the output correctly displayed in the browser. It works; however, when I update the text file, the contents do not display in the browser until I do a **ctrl-F5** to hard refresh the page.

```
<div id="outage"><object width=475 data="outage.txt"></object></div>
```

How can I refresh the DIV or OBJECT to correctly display the data in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you mean? Ajax can be used in this process.
If you want what has been written in the file to be moved to the 'div' immediately after the 'save' then I don't think it's possible to do it except by back-end

```
<div id="outage">
  <object width=475 data="outage.txt"></object>
</div>
<button class="bttn">Update</button>

<script>

   document.querySelector(".bttn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {   
      e.preventDefault()
      document.querySelector('#outage').innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector('#outage').innerHTML = `<object width=475 
      data="outage.txt"></object>`;
   });

</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution.
- I added additional text to my "outage.txt" file and refreshed the browser (F5) - the new text did not display.
- I clicked the new "update" button - the new text did not display.
- I pressed ctrl-F5 - the new text displayed.

How do I ensure that users coming to my webpage will get updated information without knowing how to hard-refresh the page?